# Bind List to DataGrid

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid

I have a problem binding a `List` to a `DataGrid` in WPF. Let me explain what I have tried.

```
public struct SomeInfo
{
    public string Name;
    public string Description;
    public string ID;
}

List<SomeInfo> arrSomeInfo;
```

The `arrSomeInfo` contains multiple items of structure `SomeInfo`.

The `DataGrid` Looks something like:

```
<DataGrid Name="grdMailbag" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="cID" Binding="{Binding ID}" Header="ID" />
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="cName" Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" />
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="cDescription" Binding="{Binding Description}" Header="Description" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I have tried the following without success:

```
this.grdMailbag.ItemsSource = arrSomeInfo; //Didn't worked
this.grdMailbag.DataContext= arrSomeInfo;  // Didn't worked
```

What is happening is that it is adding the rows as per `List arrSomeInfo` but all the rows are blank.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change this:

```
public struct SomeInfo
{
    public string Name;
    public string Description;
    public string ID;
}
```

to this:

```
public class SomeInfo
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public string ID {get;set;}
}
```

WPF does not support binding to fields. Only properties. And a `struct` is not an appropiate type for the data you're trying to represent.